# JavaScript id selector isn't working? not sure whats going wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery

The important HTML

```
 <div class="input-group">
     <input type="text" id="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for User">
           <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button class="btn btn-default" id="user_search" type="button"><i id="usersearchicon" class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
            </span>
 </div>
 <div id="user_results">
 </div>
```

The jQuery code that works

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#user_search").click(function(){
        var q = $(".form-control").val().split(/[ ,]+/).join(',');
        $("#user_results").load("{% url 'search' %}?q=" + q);
     });
});
</script>
```

The jquery code that is broken and I would rather use. The #q id I used to replace the .form-control and the ajaxstart ajaxstop stuff is breaking it I think.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#user_search").click(function(){
        var q = $("#q").val().split(/[ ,]+/).join(',');
        $("#user_results").load("{% url 'search' %}?q=" + q);
     });
});
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    $("#usersearchicon").replaceWith("<i id="usersearchicon" class="fa-li fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>");
}).ajaxStop(function() {
    $("#usersearchicon").replaceWith("<i id="usersearchicon" class="fa fa-search"></i>");
});
</script>
```

Any idea whats going wrong I'm new to javascript and jQuery, and I'm struggling with getting things to work and finding the syntax errors. I feel like I'm 95% there but can't figure out whats wrong.

I used some of this code as a starting place to build from http://www.nomadjourney.com/2009/01/using-django-templates-with-jquery-ajax/

EDIT: fixed id q quotation marks can't believe that was it haha. ajaxStart code still broken.

Comment: Your question is in regards to the ID selector, which was addressed. You should accept the answer and create a new question for the second issue.

Comment: I was going to. I have to wait 2 minutes to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look closely at the quotation marks around 'q' when defining the ID in HTML - they are special stylized quotes. Change them to regular quotation marks and it should work!

Comment: that fixed the first part! thanks the ajaxStart stuff still isn't working though :(

Comment: lines like this `"<i id="usersearchicon" class="fa fa-search"></i>"` look improperly escaped, switch the inner quotes to `'` - or better yet instead of using replaceWith, add and remove classes to the element as needed. `addClass`, `removeClass`